# How event listeners in the propagation path get queued in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, event-loop

Consider the following example:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="target">Click and watch console.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const target = document.getElementById("target");
    const body = document.body;

    body.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("event bubbled to body");
    });

    target.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("target (first listener)");
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("setTimeout");
      })
    });

    target.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // blocking code
      for (let i = 0; i < 10 ** 9; i++) {}
      console.log("target (second listener)");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

The output in the console is

```
target (first listener)
target (second listener)
event bubbled to body
setTimeout
```

`setTimeout` is outputted after event bubbling finishes, and my explanation is:

- Each event listener would queue a job in the message queue.
- When an event is dispatched, jobs for all event listeners in the propagation path (in this case, 3) get queued at once, in order.
- When `setTimeout` is executed in the event handler, its job is then queued behind all the event listeners.

Is my understanding correct? W3C spec [mentions](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#sync-async)

> Each event in this virtual queue is delayed until the previous event
>   has completed its propagation behavior, or been canceled.

But it didn't elaborate how the event propagation is handled in terms of queuing. Can anyone provide more insights or point me to some documentation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to add a timeout in milliseconds to your `setTimeout();` function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  //more code
}, milliseconds);
```